# I cant connect mysql database with fiber using golang

Tags: mysql, go

I'm new on golang and i want to connect localhost mysql. I'm using mysql-workbench for gui and it's using 3306 port. When i build project i'm getting
`listen tcp4 :3306: bind: address already in use` error. If i change port from app.Listen it's working but won't connect my mysql database. How can i solve this issue ? Anyone help me please ?

```
package db

 import (
  "database/sql"
  "fmt"

  _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
  )

var db *sql.DB

func Connection() {
  database, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:123456789@/deneme")

  if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
  }
 fmt.Print("database connection OK")
 db = database
 }

func DB() *sql.DB {
  return db
}
```

Also that's my handlers

```
package handlers

 import (
"fmt"
"go-login/db"
"log"

"github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
)

func Handlers() {

app := fiber.New()

app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    return c.SendString("Hello, World !")
})

app.Post("/register", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    data, err := db.DB().Query("INSERT INTO user(email,password) VALUES('abcd@g.com','123456')")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(data.Columns())
    return c.SendString("OK")
})

log.Fatal(app.Listen(":3306"))
}
```

Comment: Why won't it connect to MySQL? You do `panic()` to output the error, so what is the error?

Comment: You certainly cannot run your fiber app on port 3306 if MySQL Server is already using that port. Only one process on a given network interface can listen on a given port, that's just how TCP works. It is a common convention that http applications use port 80, and MySQL Server uses port 3306. Both of these may be configured, but those are the typical defaults.

Answer (score 3):

change your port to anything else
example:

```golang
log.Fatal(app.Listen(":80"))
```

as a default http application.
or

```golang
log.Fatal(app.Listen(":8000"))
```

if you want.

You cannot use a port that another application is using.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but can i connect my mysql with using 8080 port ?

Comment: I did not understand your question very well. I'll repeat your question and correct me if I misunderstood.
Is it possible to run mysql on port :8080?
The answer is yes. You need to change the mysql settings . But it is best to leave mysql at the default setting  :3306.

Comment: No, you dont understand me. If i change the app.Listen(":3306) to :8080 it's working fine, ok but after changing the 8080 from fiber listen i can not connect my mysql server because my mysql server running on 3306 port so i cant work with localhost database. Do you understand my question bro ?

Comment: you don`t call ```Connection()``` function

Comment: I call in main.go . I didnt share main file but it just have connection and handlers func.

Comment: Anyway, this is a different question from the main question
Open a new question and display this problem with all the code. I will copy your code for reproduce the problem in my device